# Role of 'axes' in keras.backend.batch_dot

Tags: python, keras

I have a custom layer to multiply two tensors A & B of size (x,1) & (1,y), where I want to produce an output C of size (x,y).

To take into account batching i.e. matrices size are actually (?,x,1) & (?,1,y), I am calling:

```
C = K.batch_dot(A,B, axes = [2,1])
```

This seems to producing the desired output, but I don't really understand what the `axes` variable represents here. My intuition is that these are the axes over which we want to perform the matrix multiplication, but I don't understand why it is in the order [2,1] rather than [1,2] (which produced an error).

Can anyone assist me in my understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the official documentation [here](https://keras.io/backend/#batch_dot)

> The lengths of axes[0] and axes[1] should be the same

In your case `A` has dimensions `(?, x, 1)` and `B` has dimensions `(?, 1, y)`.

So its quite clear that from `axis = [2, 1]`, second dimension of `A` i.e. `1` equals first dimensions of `B` i.e. `1` (axis dims starts from 0) and produces the desired results.